# Reproduce Socket Hangup in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am reproducing a socket hangup error in nodeJS with socket.io or simple http module, for testing purposes. I have tried solutions on github but none of them actually produce the socket hangup error in my case.

Can anyone guide me how to create a socket hangup error locally with nodejs?

Comment: if you don't need to actually see the physical conditions you could just .emit the types of events you want to simulate to run your tests; mock the socket behavior.

Comment: @Catalyst but i need to reproduce the issue and find out the scenario where this issue occurs so that i can add proper catches

Comment: I looked around and the best bet sounded like the linux netem tool, which can be used to simulate lots of things.

Comment: Does this scenario works with nodeJS socket.io?